# Deploying VSTO Addin with Windows Installer

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I found the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx

But in my solution I do not have a OfficeAddInSetup project so I assume I am to add a second project with installshield to achieve this, but in the docs it references VSTO 2010 redistributable.  I am using 2013.  Are the directions any different for using the VSTO 2013 redistributable?

Thanks for any advice you can offer for deploying a VSTO outlook addin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [page you mentioned](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) in the post describes how to create a new setup project.

1. In Visual Studio, open the Office project that you want to deploy.
2. On the menu bar, choose File, Add, New Project.
   The Add New Project dialog box opens.
3. In the templates pane, expand Other Project Types, and then choose the Setup and Deployment template.
4. In the list of project types for Setup and Deployment, choose InstallShield Limited Edition Project, name the project, and then choose the OK button.
   The InstallShield setup project that you just created appears in your solution.

There is no VSTO 2013. VS2013 includes VSTO2010.